# Text color of nav bar not changing

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I in my wordpress menu bar one menu item is customized

```
        #menu-item-2722{background:#6AA985;color:#fff;}
```

but the text on the particular menu item was not displaying in white
 it was same normal color as other menu items

i have also tried

```
           .nav li a #menu-item-2722 {color:#fff;}
```

so how can i change the color of the text of the menu item 2722

my existing  nav  css is

```
       nav a {
        position: relative;
        color: #444;
      display: block;
    z-index: 100;
       text-decoration: none;
            }
```

but if i change color in this whole nav will cange i only want 1 particular item  changed

Comment: can you post some of your markup?

Comment: [link](http://natural.tv/) check the shop tab in the link i need the shop text to be white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchor tag within `#menu-item-2722` is not coloured white because the CSS selector `.nav a` (which is currently styling the anchor tag) is more specific than `#menu-item-2722` since you are not inlcuding the `a` selector.

So you would need to use

```
#menu-item-2722 a {
    background:#6AA985;
    color:#fff;
}
```